# Clone mercurial repository to external repository

Tags: mercurial, backup, clone, commit

I have a mercurial server, running [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/), that I commit my code to. My client has a [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) installation and has requested that code I modify for them be stored on their server (understandable).

I would like to still commit to RhodeCode and after a successful commit, push these changes to their repository automatically. They have their code in both an SVN repository and a mercurial repository. I am allowed to commit to either - and they handle the synchronization between the two. My assumption is that it'd be easier to push to a mercurial repository.

I have a changegroup hook in mind, but I have a few technical questions on how this should work.

What is the best way to handle both receiving and pushing out to an external repository though?

```
User ----> RhodeCode ----> Redmine
```

At the RhodeCode step/changegroup hook, how do I forward on my changes? Can I do it directly from the main repository or am I forced to clone it into another directory and push *that* to the client?

Is there a better way to maintain my master repository and push my client's changes on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with this; [the Mercurial hook in Buildbot](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/manual/cfg-changesources.html#mercurial-hook) works this way, doesn't it?